# jQuery UI Date Picker Not Working

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to get the jQuery UI date picker working and failing miserably.

I've got a simple form on my page that can be seen [here](http://www.danthegeek.co.uk/competition/#Apply) but no matter what I do it fails to show the date picker. There seems to be no errors thrown up. I've got this working fine on other small test sites but for some reason it's not working here ...and driving me nuts!

I've got some html:

```
<tr>
 <td>Select Time</td>
 <td>
   <div><input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" value="" class="hasDatepicker" />
   </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

... and javascript:

```
   $('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong and I desperately need to get this working soon.

The end goal is to actually use Time Date Picker from [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Comment: can you please let us know if the issue is resolved.  If so please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$('.hasDatepicker').datepicker();`

You have a class called `hasDatepicker`.

By the way, it is a poor idea to give the textbox the id `datepicker` and the name `datepicker` given that jquery is using `datepicker()`.  And if it wasn't bad, its bad enough after another developer looks at your code.